# joining and renaming columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following are my dataframes:

df1:

```
pri  sec0  sec1  sec2
ACL  EMR   DFG   XHD
ABC  MKB   JKL   KLF
XYZ  LMN   SDF   GHY
```

df2:

```
name loc
ACL 12
EMR 23
DFG 431
XHD 48
ABC 55
MKB 699
JKL 70
KLF 82
XYZ 93
LMN 10
SDF 235
GHY 53
```

I'm trying to join each of the pri,sec0,sec1... columns of df1 with name column of df2 and want to append loc column to each of the matched elements of pri,sec0,sec1...(as pri_loc,sec0_loc... respectively)

following is the required output:

```
pri  pri_loc  sec0  sec0_loc  sec1  sec1_loc  sec2  sec2_loc
ACL  12       EMR   23        DFG   431       XHD   48
ABC  55       MKB   699       JKL   70        KLF   82
XYZ  93       LMN   10        SDF   235       GHY   53
```

Can I get suggestions on how to achieve this..?

Comment: I've tried joining individual columns with name (Eg: primary with name to get create pri_loc, sec0 and name to get sec0_loc....). But I'm trying to find a efficient way, which can give me desired output in one or two steps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) new `DataFrame` created by [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) all values by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then add [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) for change columns names and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for sorting columns:

```
df=df1.join(df1.replace(df2.set_index('name')['loc']).add_suffix('_loc')).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   pri  pri_loc sec0  sec0_loc sec1  sec1_loc sec2  sec2_loc
0  ACL       12  EMR        23  DFG       431  XHD        48
1  ABC       55  MKB       699  JKL        70  KLF        82
2  XYZ       93  LMN        10  SDF       235  GHY        53
```

Detail:

```
print (df1.replace(df2.set_index('name')['loc']).add_suffix('_loc'))
   pri_loc  sec0_loc  sec1_loc  sec2_loc
0       12        23       431        48
1       55       699        70        82
2       93        10       235        53
```

EDIT:

> if I have one more column say `ternary` in `df1` and I do not want to join it with name of df2 but I want to reatin as it is in output

Then use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ternary')
df = (df1.join(df1.replace(df2.set_index('name')['loc']).add_suffix('_loc'))
         .sort_index(axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df)
```

Comment: what if I have one more column say ternary in df1 and I do not want to join it with name of df2 but I want to reatin as it is in output??

Comment: Solutuion is same, only first step is `df1 = df1.set_index('ternary')` and last add `.reset_index()`

Comment: can you please add a complete solution in comments??

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.